# Downgrade removes new versions of executables but does not reinstall old versions

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have build two versions of my application installer. A version 1.0.0.0 and a version 1.0.1.0.
In a prebuild step the application's executables are spiked with the selected version.

In order to allow downgrades the attribute AllowDowngrades in MajorUpgrade is set to 'yes'.

After installing 1.0.0.0 I upgrade the installation by running the 1.0.1.0 installer. The executables are properly upgraded.
Then I run the 1.0.0.0 installer again to downgrade the installation back to 1.0.0.0. 
The installation completes and the executables with version 1.0.1.0 are removed;
But the executables with version 1.0.0.0 are not reinstalled. They are just missing.

I do not understand why this is happening. I could understand if the installer had refused to overwrite newer executables, but why are the newer executables removed?
Is there something else I have to do to make downgrades possible?

The beginning of my Product.wxs:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <!-- Including defines. -->
  <?include Defines.wxi ?>
  <Product Id="*"
        Name="$(var.ProductName) $(var.MajorMinorVersion)"
        Language="1033"
        Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
        Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)"
        UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeGuid)">

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" AllowDowngrades='yes' AllowSameVersionUpgrades='no' />
    ...
```

Comment: Try setting MajorUpgrade schedule to afterInstallValidate and test again - see if that works. Problem has to do with MSI bugs. Downgrading is a bad practice, can you eliminate it?

Comment: I can't eliminate it for rather embarassing reasons. Setting "afterInstallValidate" did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REINSTALLMODE had to be changed from default `omus` to `amus`:

```
<Property Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="amus" />
```

From Microsoft documentation:

```
o   Reinstall if the file is missing or is an older version.
a   Force all files to be reinstalled, regardless of checksum or version.
```

With this change the executables are reinstalled on the downgrade in the right version.

Comment: If you have any merge modules or shared files in your MSI this can cause a number of unfortunate side-effects centering around down-grading of files and inconsistent file versions.

Comment: You can also overwrite settings files unexpectedly - last time I checked. You check too? :-).

Comment: Fortunately, the installer is very basic and does not have to be future-proof. 
Yes, A custom dialog asks if config files should be overwritten.